# Share dynamic link of web page on Facebook wall?

Tags: php, facebook, html, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

i have created web page in PHP who searches nearer places.have a look on below screen shot.
[image]

now i want to share this place on my facebook wall.now see below i found some results and i have clicked on OSHO rajneesh asharm to get details,now i want to share this OSHO on facebook wall. i am not getting where should i put Facebook logo and how to get link of particular selected item.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for Facebook "places" using this query:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DPune%20Lohegaon%26type%3Dplace

You can also expand upon the type of search if you know the lat/long coordinates of the center of your search.  Then you can do something like:
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000`